# 'when you travel to Boston'

Tags: meaning, tense

a. Tell me when you travel to Boston.

b. Tell me when you are travelling to Boston.

c. Tell me when you are going to travel to Boston.

d. Tell me when you will travel to Boston.

I am assuming that the clause following 'tell me' is the object of 'tell me'. What you are telling me is the time at which you travel/are going to travel/ etc. to Boston.

In that case which sentence implies that the speakers expects an answer **now**?

I think (a) could be used when the addressee travels to Boston regularly, but the others can't. Is that correct?

I don't think there is much difference between the three last ones. It seems to me that they could be used whether the speaker expects a reply 'now' or later.

I think (a) could be used instead of the others if the travel has already been planned.

Is that correct?

Comment: Although _When do you travel to Boston?_ is fine for asking for an answer now, I would probably understand (a) to mean _The next time you plan to travel to Boston, please let me know_.

Answer (score 3):

There is a bit of ambiguity, because "when" can introduce a nominal or adverbial clause. Let's consider both cases.

If "when" introduces a nominal clause, then the sentence's meaning is similar to "tell me the date on which . . ." The nominal clause functions as a direct object, as you indicate. In that case, any of the four options is perfectly fine. The speaker probably expects an answer now, although he or she doesn't explicitly say so.

If "when" introduces an adverbial clause, then the clause modifies the verb "tell". (Note that the listener might travel to Boston many times and tell the speaker about it many times--in which case "when" could be synonymous with "whenever"--or only once.) In this case, options (a) and (b) would be the most natural. Options (c) and (d) are possible but emphasize that the travelling will occur after the telling. Note that the speaker does not expect an answer now; the adverbial clause describes when the telling should occur.

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed reply! I have another question if I may. If in (c) the "when clause" is an adverbial clause 'will' would basically mean 'are willing to', right? It is as if the addressee is at present unwilling to travel to Boston.

Comment: (c) doesn't include "will". Do you mean (d)? If so, then no, "will" does not mean "are willing to". It marks the future tense. The speaker might mean, for example, "in the future, whenever you will travel to Boston, tell me the day before so that I am prepared". English verb tenses are not very strict, though, so other meanings may be possible, too.

Comment: Thank you so much, Kate and MarcInManhattan.